# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'userData' available as request attribute

Tags: spring-boot, validation, thymeleaf

I am trying to follow [this](https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-security/registration-with-spring-security/) to display some error messages for the user when trying to register and not entering the correct input or leaving the input empty. I am getting in the console the error in the title and the page display this error message `There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).`

I have a class User that does not implement Serializable and exactly like the Userdate.

`UserData.java`

```
public class UserData implements Serializable{
    
    @NotEmpty(message = "First name can not be empty")
    private String firstName;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Last name can not be empty")
    private String lastName;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Email can not be empty")
//    @Email(message = "Please provide a valid email id")
    private String email;
    
    @NotEmpty(message = "username can not be empty")
    private String username;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Password can not be empty")
    private String password;
    
    private Set<Role> roles=new HashSet<>();
```

`UserService.java`

```
public void save(UserData userData) throws EmailAlreadyExistException {
        if(checkIfUserEmailExist(userData.getEmail())) {
            throw new EmailAlreadyExistException("This email already exist. Use different email.");
        }

        User user = new User();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(userData, user);
        encodePassword(user, userData);
        userData.setRoles(new HashSet<Role> (Arrays.asList(new Role("user"))));
        userRepository.save(user);
        
    }
    
    // ----------------------------------------------------- helper methods for user validation ------------------------------------------- 
    
     private boolean checkIfUserEmailExist(String email) {
            return userRepository.findByEmail(email) !=null ? true : false;
        }
     
     private void encodePassword( User user, UserData userData){
            user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        }
```

`RegisterationController.java`

```
@Controller
public class RegisterationController {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    
    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String getRegisterPage(ModelMap model) {
        User user = new User();
        model.put("user", user);
        return "register";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/register")
    public String postRegister(final @Valid UserData userData, final BindingResult bindingResult, final Model model) {
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("register", userData);
            return "register";
        }
        
        try {
            userService.save(userData);
        } catch (EmailAlreadyExistException e) {
            bindingResult.rejectValue("email", 
                                      "userData.email", 
                     "This email is alraedy taken");
            model.addAttribute("register", userData);
//          e.printStackTrace();
            return "register";
        }
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

`register.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body class="hold-transition register-page">
  <div class="register-box">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body register-card-body">
        <p class="login-box-msg">Register a new account</p>

        <form action="#" th:action="@{/register}" th:object="${userData}" method="post">
          <div class="alert alert-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('*')}">
          <p th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('*')}" th:text="${err}"></p>
        </div>
        </form>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  th:field="*{firstName}" placeholder="First Name" th:errorclass="is-invalid">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <div class="input-group-text">
            <span class="fas fa-user"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control"  th:field="*{lastName}" placeholder="Last Name" th:errorclass="is-invalid">

          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-user"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
       <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" th:field="*{email}" placeholder="Email" th:errorclass="is-invalid">

          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-envelope"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
         <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{username}" placeholder="username" th:errorclass="is-invalid">

          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-envelope"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" th:field="*{password}" placeholder="Password" th:errorclass="is-invalid">

          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        
    </div>
    <!-- /.form-box -->
  </div><!-- /.card -->
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when opening the register page you are sending the `user` object

```
@GetMapping("/register")
public String getRegisterPage(ModelMap model) {
    Useruser = new User();
    model.put("user", user);
    return "register";
}
```

and on the page you are trying to load the `userData` object

```
th:object="${userData}"
```

you need that the object sent to the page, be named `userData`, or on the page use the object named `user`..

like:

```
@GetMapping("/register")
public String getRegisterPage(ModelMap model) {
    Useruser = new User();
    model.put("userData", user);
    return "register";
}
```

or

```
th:object="${user}"
```